# Fastest way to find which two elements of a list another item is closest to in python

Tags: python, list

The input is a sorted list of elements and an external item. For example:

```
list_ = [0, 3.5, 5.8, 6.2, 88]
item = 4.4
```

What is the fastest way of finding out which two elements in `list_` `item` falls between? In this case for example, the two numbers would be 3.5 and 5.8. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the input is sorted, you're best bet algorithmically is to use the `bisect` module -- e.g. [`bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left)

```
>>> list_ = [0, 3.5, 5.8, 6.2, 88]
>>> item = 4.4
>>> bisect.bisect_left(list_, item)
2
```

The items you want reside at indices `bisect_left(list_, item)` and 
`bisect_left(list_, item) - 1`

This should give you a result in `O(logN)` searches -- It doesn't get much better than that from an algorithm standpoint.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`bisect` module's `bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect) function to get the index at which the `item` fits in

```
list_, item = [0, 3.5, 5.8, 6.2, 88], 4.4
from bisect import bisect
print bisect(list_, item)
# 2
```

**Remember** Your `list_` has to be sorted, to be able to use the functions in `bisect` module.

Answer (score 1):

I would use numpy:

```
from numpy import *
x = array([0, 3.5, 5.8, 6.2, 88])
item = 4.4

i= argmin(abs(x-item))
print(i)
```